# AWS Step Functions Inputs

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an input json with an array inside it and I want to access that array as a parallel state input and another part of the input json as the input too. I have something like this.

```
 "New_Dict": {
"splits": [
  {
    "Key1": 0,
    "k": 2,
    "keys": [
      0,
      1
    ],
    "j": 0
  },
  {
    "Key1": 0,
    "k": 2,
    "keys": [
      0,
      1
    ],
    "j": 1
  }
],
"Split_Upload_Duration_splitfurther": 1349,
"Download_Duration_splitfurther": 1768
```

}
}

I want to use the array "splits" as ItemsPath and "Split_Upload_Duration_splitfurther" and "Download_Duration_splitfurther" as InputPath. How can I go about this?